# Correctness of Wiktionary IPA Translation

Tags: ipa, transcription

The logo for Wikimedia's [Wiktionary project](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Wiktionary:Main_Page) features a narrow transcription IPA of the term:[image]

Adding English syllabification produces [ˈwɪk.ʃənˌrɪ] (`WICK-shun-rih`), which I find strange.  I personally pronounce it as [ˈwɪk.ʃən.ɛːɹˌi] (`WICK-shun-air-ee`).

I am aware that some dialects allow dropping syllables in fluent speech.

My question is about the last syllable.  The ending feels quite wrong; in particular, I remember learning about a specific preclusion against lax vowels word-finally.

Is there a problem here?  Is there a dialect that pronounces this word in this way?  If so, what is it?

Comment: Check the UK pronunciation for [dictionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/dictionary)

Comment: For the last syllable there is quite a choice for both the "r" and the "i". Some with use a tap/flap symbol or a retroflex symbol for the "r". For the "i" some will use the "short" ɪ, some will use the "normal" one with length mark i:, and some will use that symbol without the length mark due to final -y varying between the other two sounds depending on dialect and idiolect. Also when American English is transcribed in IPA it's usual to not use length marks for any vowels.

Comment: @hippietrail silly questions: I'm doing a narrow surface transcription (`[...]`).  Is not marking length marks obligatory?  Relatedly, in the current answer, why is the poster using lexical transcription (`/.../`)?

Comment: I'd hardly call that a 'narrow' transcription of 'wiktionary', it seems pretty phonemic to me. And it's got a word-final lax vowel, surely that's incorrect?

Comment: @GastonÜmlaut: hence my question.  My transcription is, I believe/hope, more "correct" in the sense of being properly narrow.

Comment: Hi, yes my criticism was aimed at the Wiktionary ipa transcript. Yours is certainly more correct and narrower (tho it could be even narrower...). I don't understand your syllabification though: you show 3 syllables, the last syllable being VCV with stress on the last V. Have you left out a syllable break? If so, the stress pattern seems unnatural (for English anyway): primary stress on 1st syllable, secondary on the fourth and last syllable.

Comment: @GastonÜmlaut: Hmmmm, you're right; I probably should have done `ɛːˌɹi`.  I was trying to agglomerate the `ɹ` into a rhotic vowel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lax vowels generally cannot end words, but there are exceptions. A more complete rule would be that English has no stressed word-final lax vowels. The unstressed vowel /ə/ can come at the end of words like "comma" and, in non-rhotic accents such as Received Pronunciation (the traditional "posh" British accent), "letter". Another unstressed final vowel that is lax in Received Pronunciation is /ɪ/, which in this position corresponds to the sound pronounced /i/ in other varieties of English. I understand that the lax pronunciation is one of the more old-fashioned features of RP, and it isn't widely used in modern British pronunciation (the change from [ɪ] to [i] is referred to as "happy-tensing").

Comment: Wow, thanks, I'll have to listen more carefully in future for this word-final [ɪ] in RP... I've never been aware of it before (I speak Oz English).

Answer (score 1):

The transcription /ˈdɪkʃ(ə)n(ə)ɹɪ/ is not very good either. In British “received pronunciation” you can say either /ˈdɪkʃənɹɪ/ or /ˈdɪkʃənəɹɪ/, but you cannot say */ˈdɪkʃnɹɪ/ or */ˈdɪkʃnəɹɪ/. The twice bracketed /(ə)/ is misleading.